# How can I populate tuple using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have this xml block:

```
<difficulties>
    <difficulty difficultyId="1">
      <parameter key="maxNumerator" value="10"></parameter>
      <parameter key="maxDenominator" value="15"></parameter>
      <parameter key="couple" value="2"></parameter>
    </difficulty>
    <difficulty difficultyId="2">
      <parameter key="maxNumerator" value="20"></parameter>
      <parameter key="maxDenominator" value="30"></parameter>
      <parameter key="couple" value="2"></parameter>
    </difficulty>
    ...
</difficulties>
```

What I would like to do, is to fetch a pattern similar to:

```
difficultyId, key, value
```

like:

```
1, maxNumerator, 10
1, maxDenominator, 10
1, couple, 2
2, maxNumerator, 20
...
```

Is there some way I can insert it into a list of tuples (assuming I have loaded the xml document into xDocument already). I'd like to use LINQ:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, string>> res = from a in xDocument.Descendants("difficulties")
                                          ...?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 var res =(from a in xDocument.Descendants("difficulty")
           from parameter in a.Elements("parameter")
           select new Tuple<string,string,string>(a.Attribute("difficultyId").Value,
                                                  parameter.Attribute("key").Value,
                                                  parameter.Attribute("value").Value)).ToList();
```